# running a django app on apache with SSL: pexpect spawn/expect doesn't work

Tags: python, django, apache, ssl, pexpect

I'm running a django app on apache 2.2 with SSL enabled. When I don't have the SSL enabled, all is well. But with security, there probably are some restrictions on how an os can fork off a process, etc. I'm not aware of those at all.

OS used: Solaris (not sure if it matters, but it could)
Django v1.4, Apache 2.2, Python 2.7

An outline of what I'm doing in one of my views:

```
def run_step(request, action):
    if (action == "action1"):
        p = subprocess.Popen("command1", 
            shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    elif (action == "action2"):
       password = mylib.getpasswd()
       ## Method 1: with pexpect
       command = pexpect.spawn('su root -c \' command2 \'')
       command.expect('[pP]assword*')
       command.sendline(password)

       ## Method 2: with subprocess and a simple command
       #command = subprocess.Popen('ls > log.file',
           shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

       ## Method 3: with subprocess stdin PIPE 
       #command = subprocess.Popen('command2', shell=True,
         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
       #command.stdin.write(password)
       #command.communicate()

       ## I tried with shell = False, 
       ## with stdin.flush() and communicate(password) too.
```

The command for 'Action1' gets executed very well. But the problem with those which need interaction like that of 'Action2'.
I tried three different methods:

- Method1: sent it using pexpect as usual but it fails - the command doesn't get executed at all.
- Method2: tried a subprocess call wihtout an interaction - works.
- Method3: tried a subprocess call with a stdin pipe to try interaction but failed again.

I'm not sure how to go about this now. Any help would be very highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

Spawned the pexpect call as a separate thread using the 'threading' module in python, and then sent the password using a sendline.

```
import threading

command = 'ls -l' #some_command
t = threading.Thread(target=some_function,args=(command,))
t.start()


def some_function(command):
    some_process = pexpect.spawn(command)
    some_process.expect('[pP]assword*')
    some_process.sendline(some_password)
    some_process.expect(pexpect.EOF,timeout=1000)
```

I don't still understand why the pexpect module, as is, did not work on the main thread. Would still appreciate any answers, but I'm going with this solution for now.